# Implicit conversion between templated class instances that use classes that inherit from one-another

Tags: c++, oop, templates, inheritance

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class Base  
{  
    public:  
        Base( int val = 0 ) : value( val ) {};  
        int value;  
};
```

Classes `A` and `B` inherit `Base`:

```
class A : public Base {};
class B : public Base {};
```

I also have a templated class with a signature similar to:

```
template < class T >
class Temp
{
    public:
        Temp ( const T & val = T() ) : m_T( val ) {};
        T m_T;        
};
```

What I am trying to do is have a function that takes pointers to `Temp<Base>` instances and act upon them:

```
void doSomething ( Temp< Base > * a, Temp< Base > * b )
{
    (*a) = (*b);
};
```

Ultimately, I would like to have `Temp<A>` and `Temp<B>` instances passed to `doSomething()`, like:

```
void
main()
{
    Temp<A> a;
    Temp<B> b;
    doSomething( &a, &b) ;
};
```

Obviously, this will not work because `Temp<A>` and `Temp<B>` are not related and there is no implicit conversion between the types (even though `A` and `B` are `Base`).

What are some of the ways this problem could be solved? Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Not only are `Temp<A>` and `Temp<B>` unrelated, you can't assign an instance of `B` to an instance of `A` either.

Comment: I guess my question boils down to, in C++, why is a basket of apples not a basket of fruits and how can I work around this without much effort?

Comment: A basket of apples IS a basket of fruits, but the mechanism you are discussing (templates) isn't a basket of anything; it's an entirely new entity, which the compiler can't tell if it's a basket, a bag, or an airplane.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename T, typename U>
void doSomething ( Temp< T > * a, Temp< U> * b ) 
{ 
    (*a) = (*b); 
};
```

Comment: Temp<t> and Temp<U> are completely different types, aren't they? Wouldn't that make the assignment line impossible?

Comment: At compile time the compiler will create a version of doSomething with the concrete types specified, and then attempt to compile the resultant function. In this case it will work, as the assignment between the specified types of U and T is valid.

Comment: @Visage my question is more regarding the assignability of a Temp<U>* to a Temp<T>*. This probably has nothing to do with doSomething(), in my mind. Where I am wrong? Thanks.

Comment: If, when types are assigned to U & T, Temp<U>* is assignable to Type<T>*, then it will compile.  If not, it won't.  So, if T & U are A & B, and Temp<A>* is assignable to Temp<B>*, everything is fine.

Comment: @James, yes in your last sentence you are re-stating my question. If a is a Temp<A> star and b is a Temp<B> star, are they EVER compatible in this manner? Does it follow that because an A start can be assigned a B star that a Temp<A> star can be assigned a Temp<B> star?

Comment: @San Jacinto: That would depend on the assignment operator of `Temp<>`

Answer (score 0):

You lose a lot of the usefulness of the inheritance relationship if you aren't careful, but if you make Temp derive off of a common base class, you can create templated members in its derived classes. What you essentially end up doing is moving your common interface of A and B into BASE, and then for specialization (how to actually carry out those functions), you refer to the TempA or TempB member in BASE (with A and B surrounded by the brackets. Editor won't le me be explicit.).